# Implementing an interface through a form class using an event

Tags: c#, .net, function, events, interface

I'm currently working on porting over some Visual Basic .NET code to c# .NET, and there's a particular part of the library I'm porting that I can't seem to get to work. Here's how it's laid out:

First, I have an interface defined as follows:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
      void EnableSave(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
```

Next, I have an inheritable form that implements the above interface:

```
public partial class frmIMyInterface : Form, Globals.IMyInterface
{
      public delegate void EnableFormSaveEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
      public event EnableFormSaveEventHandler EnableFormSave;

      public void EnableSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            EnableFormSave.Invoke(sender, e);
      }
}
```

So far so good. Then, I create a form that implements frmIMyInterface:

```
public partial class frmMyNewForm : frmIMyInterface
{
...
```

In that form, I have a method defined to handle the event:

```
private void EnableSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.cmdSave.Enabled = true;
}
```

Then, in the designer code for the form, the handler delegate is defined as follows:

```
this.EnableFormSave += new frmIMyInterface.EnableFormSaveEventHandler(this.EnableSave);
```

My project builds normally, however, when I try to open `frmMyNewForm` with the form designer, I get a splash screen that says, "To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved: The Method 'EnableSave' cannot be the method for an event because a class this class derives from already defines the method."

The VisualBasic.NET code that I ported had everything defined exactly as I have it defined, but worked fine. I can't see any problem, and it seems like .NET should know the difference between the method definition in the base class that raises the event, and the handler defined in the derived form that gets set as the event handler.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your frmMyNewForm has *two* EnableSave() methods.  The one it inherits from the base class and another private one.  You also got a warning about that, recommending to use the *new* keyword if you meant to do this.  You don't want to do this, there's no point.  You also made a mistake in the frmIMyInterface.EnableSave() method, it will crash and burn when no event handler subscribes the event.  It also doesn't follow the event raising pattern, it ought to be a protected virtual method named OnEnableSave().  Keep in mind that C# is not like VB.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to rename either your event handler or your event. Otherwise the call is ambiguous.

So this works:

```
this.EnableFormSave += new frmIBGInterface.EnableFormSaveEventHandler(this.OnEnableSave);

private void OnEnableSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.cmdSave.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So... I guess VisualBasic.NET just doesn't care and figures it out without error?

Also... the event is named `EnableFormSave`... so it is different.

Comment: Not sure why, I think it shouldn't work there either.

Comment: When I try to make this change, as soon as I change the name of the method where the code is assigning the delegate method to the event handler, I get this error: 

"No overload for 'OnEnableSave' matches delegate 'frmIMyInterface.EnableFormSaveEventHandler"

Comment: I don't see why. Changing the name does nothing with the signature. Can you confirm that you changed both lines?

Comment: Ah... I had removed the parameters. Put them back, and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: Since you are new: Please don't forget to mark the question answered if the answer was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The usual pattern in c# is to name the method that invokes the event OnEnableSave, and make this virtual so that derived classes can override the behaviour without having to attach to their own events. So in frmIMyInterface:

```
public virtual void OnEnableSave(EventArgs e)
  {
        //EnableFormSave.Invoke(sender, e);

        // This is the usual way to invoke an event in c#
        var handler = EnableFormSave;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
  }
```

then in frmMyNewForm

```
public override void OnEnableSave(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnEnableSave(e);
    this.cmdSave.Enabled = true;
}
```

That said, it's quite weird to make methods that invoke events public. I'd probably name the interface method something like EnableSave(), and then call OnEnableSave() from that method and make OnEnableSave() protected.

Comment: Could you expand on how you think this should be properly implemented? I'm not opposed to changing how it's done... remember, this is a port. I'd rather do it properly than do it poorly just because that's how it was done in VB. :)

The objective is to have an event that is inherited, and fires when data changes, and force the derived form to implement a method to do something when that event fires (like enable the save button).

Comment: Well how is your application currently structured? Where is the code that detects the data change and calls IMyInterface.EnableSave()?

Comment: Sorry, still learning how this works here...

The idea is, it's a library, and there's a class that you pass your form to, and it spins through all of the controls on the form, and adds the eventhandler to the corresponding "...Changed" event based on the control type. 

`
    private frmIMyInterface frmFoo;

    if (_ctrl is TextBox ) {
        _ctrl.TextChanged += new EventHandler(frmFoo.EnableSave);
    } else if ...
`

So as the form builds, it should add the event to each control, and when the control data changes, the event should fire and allow the save button to be enabled.

Comment: I've never heard of anything like that before! IMO you should either leave it to the form to attach to the changed events of its controls and set the enabled state of its save button, or go for a tried and tested pattern such as MVC where the form would enable the save button when a CanSave property on the controller is set to true.

Comment: If you want to do it your way then I don't see the need for an event. Just define void EnableSave() on IMyInterface and implement it with an abstract method on frmIMyInterface. This will force frmMyNewForm to override EnableSave(), where it can enable the save button.

Comment: I got it working with the help on here. Basically, the event fires whenever data changes in an editable form control, which in turn immediately enables the save button. It's pretty cool... even if it is a little goofy in the implementation. I've cleaned it up as best as I can based on the assistance given here, it's way better than it was for sure! Thanks! :)